# ¿Cómo obtengo los valores de los intervalos realizados con cut?

Tags: r

Hola actualmente tengo una serie de datos, y los estoy representando con una tabla de frecuencias, dividida por intérvalos que son los siguientes:

Los intérvalos han sido calculados con:

```
cut(datos, nclass.Sturges(datos))

(4.95,14] (14,23] (23,32] (32,41] (41,50] (50,59.1]
```

El caso es que quiero calcular la media y la moda y por lo tanto necesito el limite inferior, por lo que quisiera saber como podría coger por ejemplo del valor `(14, 23]` el `14`.

Gracias.

Comment: SIempre es bueno mostrar que has intentado para resolver pues 1) Corriges posibles errores que tu tengas y 2) da la sensación de que no intentaste nada y buscas a alquien que haga el trabajo por ti ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es:

1. Guardar los datos categorizados en una nueva variable

   ```
   datosc <- cut(datos, nclass.Sturges(datos))
   ```
2. Obtener los niveles del factor obtenido

   ```
   lvls <- levels(datosc)
   ```
3. Luego con la función strsplit, dividir cada texto (`'(41,50]'`) por la coma

   ```
   cortes <- strsplit(lvls, ",")
   ```
4. Lo anterior devuelve una lista en donde cada elemento es el vector de los los dos valores, por lo que necesitamos el primer elemento de cada vector, para esto usamos la función `lapply` para aplicar la función `head` a cada elemento de la lista con el parámetro `1`

   ```
   primerel <- lapply(cortes, head, 1)
   ```
5. Al valor anterior le sacamos el primer paréntesis

   ```
   primerel <- gsub("\\(", "", primerel)
   ```
6. Finalmente lo forzamos a un valor numérico

   ```
   primerel <- as.numeric(primerel)
   ```

Ejemplo

```
> datos <- rnorm(10)
> 
> datosc <- cut(datos, nclass.Sturges(datos))
> 
> lvls <- levels(datosc)
> lvls
[1] "(-1.33,-0.934]"  "(-0.934,-0.536]" "(-0.536,-0.138]" "(-0.138,0.26]"       "(0.26,0.66]"    
> 
> cortes <- strsplit(lvls, ",")
> cortes
[[1]]
[1] "(-1.33"  "-0.934]"

[[2]]
[1] "(-0.934" "-0.536]"

[[3]]
[1] "(-0.536" "-0.138]"

[[4]]
[1] "(-0.138" "0.26]"  

[[5]]
[1] "(0.26" "0.66]"

> 
> primerel <- lapply(cortes, head, 1)
> primerel
[[1]]
[1] "(-1.33"

[[2]]
[1] "(-0.934"

[[3]]
[1] "(-0.536"

[[4]]
[1] "(-0.138"

[[5]]
[1] "(0.26"

> 
> primerel <- gsub("\\(", "", primerel)
> primerel
[1] "-1.33"  "-0.934" "-0.536" "-0.138" "0.26"  
> 
> primerel <- as.numeric(primerel)
> primerel
[1] -1.330 -0.934 -0.536 -0.138  0.260
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la función sub de R para cada caso. 
Esa función remplaza un caracter por uno a elección. Aquí por ejemplo reemplazamos todo lo que está después de la coma, para cada elemento, por un vacio en `sub(",.*", "", x)` por ejemplo le damos `"(2.25, 67]"` va a retornar `"(2.25"` luego para sacar el paréntesis inicial le haces un `substring` y se lo aplicar a todo el conjunto de datos con un `sapply`.

sería más o menos así

#### Guardar datos en un array

```
cl <- cut(datos, nclass.Sturges(datos))
```

#### aplicar a cada elemento del array

```
infs <- sapply(b, function(x) substring(sub(",.*", "", x),2,5))
```

#### Convertir a numérico

```
infs <- as.numeric(infs)
```

Espero que ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podés hacer con expresiones regulares usando la función sub.

```
intervalos <- cut(datos, nclass.Sturges(datos))
intervalos <- as.character(intervalos)
lim_inf <- as.numeric(sub("\\((.*),.*\\]", "\\1", intervalos))
lim_inf
```

De forma similar podés hacerlo para el limite superior realizando cambios minimos en el patrón de la función sub.

Answer (score 0):

Para dividir una distribución de probabilidad de una variable en partes iguales, utilizamos los cuantiles. La división puede ser de los grupos que estimemos oportunos, pero lo habituales es sacar cuartiles o quintiles.

#Si dividimos la distribución en 5 partes, tendremos los quintiles. útil para realizar 5 grupos de datos.

quantile(Tabla$Variable,prob=c(0,0.20,0.4,0.6,0.8,1))

En cada uno de los intervalos, tendremos un 20% de los datos.

También podemos elegir otras probabilidades:

quantile(Tabla$Variable,prob=c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1)).

En este caso, la distribución, queda dividida en 4 partes.

Un saludo.

#o los valores  sigma

quantile(dfclientes$TotalAmount,prob=c(0.6826,0.9546,0.9973,0.999937,0.9999943,0.99999998))

Una vez dividido, para cada uno de los cuantiles, grupos o intervalos, se pueden calcular las estadísticas descriptivas que queramos: median(), mean(), mode()...